# Convert a matrix to a 2d data frame in r

Tags: r

I have simple matrix and I'd like to create combinations of rows and columns for all values in matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("col1","col2")
rownames(mat) <- c("row1","row2","row3")
```

And desired output:

```
cols  rows  value
col1  row1  2
col1  row2  4
col1  row3  3
col2  row1  1
col2  row2  5
col2  row3  7
```

Is there any simple and fast solution for that. Many thanks for any of your advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `melt` of the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
mat <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("col1","col2")
rownames(mat) <- c("row1","row2","row3")
melt(mat)
```